# What are the rectangular black markers shown in the roads of Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, symbology, road, mathematica

I'm doing some image processing to quantify the connectivity of London's roads. I'm not a geographer or map-expert and I would like to know what are the black rectangular nodes/markers in this map.

[image]

[source](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=%2051.5%20-0.116667&%5C%20zoom=10&size=600x600&scale=2&style=feature:road.highway%257%20%5C%20Ccolor:0x000000%20%257%20Cweight:1%257%20Cvisibility:on). The map appears as shown when imported into Mathematica.

Comment: Your source link doesn't appear to match the image posted or show an example of it. If I were to hazard a guess it looks like they're incorrectly rendered shield labels for route/highway numbers, or masks for them. More info on the process or exact steps you're taking might be helpful.

Comment: The map appears as shown when imported into Mathematica. Clicking on it gives a different image. See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79066/mathematical-morphology-removing-text-features-from-image-while-keeping-connec

Comment: If you want to import an image, why don't you use the static map api, which gives an image as an output